# Flash: Randomly generate numbers 0-9 repetitively

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Basically I need the "image" of fast changing numbers. I am planning on having a series of these in a line, sort of like the matrix (how the numbers change repeatedly). I want them to basically generate the numbers 0-9 over and over pretty fast (sort of like milliseconds on a stopwatch), until I have them fade out.

I am fairly new to flash, so if you guys could help me out with a code I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated to get a random number between 0 and 9, Math.random is the way to go:

```
var n:int = Math.floor(Math.Random()*10);
```

But to address your second question, of how to get it so it does this every millisecond

```
import flash.utils.setInterval;
import flash.utils.clearInterval;

//variable for the intervalID, 
//and the variable that will be assigned the random number
var rnGenIID:uint, rn:int;

//function to update the rn variable 
//to the newly generated random number
function updateRN():void{
    rn = random0to9();
    //as suggested, you could just use:
    //rn = int(Math.random()*10);
    //but I figured you might find having it as a function kind of useful, 
    //...
    //the trace is here to show you the newly updated variable
    trace(rn);
}
function random0to9 ():int{
    //in AS3, when you type a function as an int or a uint,
    //so instead of using:
    //return Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    //or
    //return int(Math.random()*10);
    //we use:
    return Math.random()*10;
}

//doing this assigns rnGenIID a number representing the interval's ID#
//and it set it up so that the function updateRN will be called every 1 ms
rnGenIID = setInterval(updateRN,1);

//to clear the interval
//clearInterval(rnGenIID);
```

Comment: Why are you using `setInterval` instead of a recursive `Timer`?

Comment: @Matt McDonald, `setTimeout`/`setInterval` are lighter-weight than `Timer` as it's a language construct. If you know what you're doing with them, they can work wonders. For helping a newbie with flash, I'd suggest `Timer`.

Comment: Well, I will answer that with a question? does it matter what order the random number came in? if not I avoid the Timer class.  I was also trying to make it easy for him and other people viewing this that might be used to javascript.

Comment: @Anthony Pace, why bother using timers at all? you probably should just attach an `ENTER_FRAME` event on the stage, and let that work as your update cycle.

Comment: you don't want to use an ENTER_FRAME event, because he wants it to update every 1 milliseconds, and the most you can do with an enter frame event is 1000/121 (because I think the limit of FPS is 121); yet, even so, it is highly unlikely you can do this if the swf is going to be doing anything else, like drawing on the stage.

Comment: drawing on the stage?  I do not believe I did any of that.  I'm really new to flash so theres nothing too complex going on in this movie.  Its a promotional video for a company. The only thing thats going on so far is things fading in/out, text here and there, and a timer script on a few frames to make it pause in between messages in the video.

Comment: @Anthony,  it dosn't matter what number it came in on.  It would actually be preferred if it came in on a random number.  I will be having multiple occurances of this on the same frame.

Answer (score 1):

just a quick tip: casting a Number ( the Math.random() * 10 ) into an int

```
int( n );
```

does the same as

```
Math.floor( n );
```

and is way faster.
we can get a Math.round() by adding .5 to n

```
int( n + .5 );
```

and a Math.ceil() by adding 1 to the result

```
int( n ) + 1;
```

here's a loop to check:

```
var n:Number;
var i:int;
var total:int = 100000;
for ( i = 0; i < total;  i++ )
{ 
    n = Math.random() * 10;
    if ( int( n ) != Math.floor( n ) ) trace( 'error floor ', n );
    if ( int( n + .5 ) != Math.round( n ) ) trace( 'error round ', n );
    if ( int( n ) + 1 != Math.ceil( n ) ) trace( 'error ceil ', n );
}
```

this, shouldn't trace anything :)

Comment: how to do use that along with an instance name? (the actual number)

Comment: not sure I understood:
var newName:String = instance.name + '_' + int( Math.random() * 10 ).toString(); returns a string made of the name of the instance a separator '_' for readability and the number as String. if your instance is called 'abc', it will give the string 'abc_X' where X is the number.